# NFT Ticket Validation

Tags: nft, validation

I am developing an app that needs Venue Ticket validation. So when our user goes to an event the vendor can check the owner of that NFT or NFTs. What methods can we use?

Right now I see signature required for Phantom wallet. Will this suffice for validation of NFT ownership?

Comment: Check cardinal.so, I saw that others NFT projects had built ticketing systems using their contracts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the backend you need to fetch the owner of the NFT. After that use signature to verify that user's wallet matches owner's wallet.

Comment: This is what I had in mind using phantom with signature. Going to prompt signature request with wallet QR code for now until I can come up with a better solution. If there is one.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of "owning" the NFT is that it is owned by the user's wallet, you can easily check if a given wallet has a given NFT without even needing the wallet's signature. For example you can see all the holdings of any wallet on Solscan, and likewise see who owns a given NFT.

For tickets which are not unique, you might consider using a Mint to create tickets and an Associated Token Account per user that stores owned tickets.

Comment: This only verifies that nft belongs to that wallet, we want to make sure the user is in their wallet and that they own that wallet.